# What's the terminal command to show detailed progress?

Tags: terminal

I'm fairly new to development, but I recall reading about a terminal 'command' that would show detailed output/progress for an action.

For instance, if I was installing ruby bundles, I could add this -xxxxx command to the end of a "bundle install" and it would show detailed/frequent progress.

Hope that makes sense...

Edit: I think I got it! '-detail'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

normally a -v (verbose) option does it for you.